# VBA - Determining if Excel Data Table range has any data/values without looping through each cell in the range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble determining if an entire range of data (one column of an Excel data table) contains any values.  Before I loop through each row of data in the range (so that it can be exported to a .CSV), I am trying to determine if there is any data whatsoever in that given column.  If not, I will just move to the next column in the Excel data table versus wasting the time it takes to loop through each cell in the column.

```
For Each tbl In WS.ListObjects

Set tblRange = tbl.Range

' Determine # of Rows and Columns
    IntEndRow = tbl.ListRows.Count
    IntEndCol = tbl.ListColumns.Count

For intTableCol = 2 To IntEndCol 'Loop thru each table column starting w/ 2nd column
```

I have tried a few different ways to determine if there are any values in the table column/range:

```
' Determine if individual column has data
    If Not IsEmpty(Range(tblRange.Cells(2, intTableCol), tblRange.Cells(IntEndRow, intTableCol))) Then
```

The above does not work because even if there are no values it is still proceeding as if there are - I may not be understanding how to use the IsEmpty correctly.  I also thought of trying the below:

```
    Set colRange = Range(tblRange.Cells(2, 2), tblRange.Cells(IntEndRow + 1, IntEndCol))
    sumData = Application.Sum(colRange)
```

However, even if there are no values in the range I am summing, it comes back with zero.  Users will be allowed to input zero as a legitimate value so I do not want that a column with a zero in it to be recognized as having no value.  I am wondering if there is a way to do this without looping through each individual cell in the range/table column?

Comment: Try using the worksheet function to count non-blank cells in the range: `WorksheetFunction.CountA(tbl.ListColumns(3).Range)`

Comment: @PeterT, thank you so much.  This should work for me.  I've Googled and Bing'd quite a bit but this function was never brought to my attention until now.  I am stil new to StackOverflow, and I don't have enough reputation points to close this out or I'm not sure if I can mark yours as the answer?